# Pass States between Components - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass some states between components however the values are always undefined.

I have a component called Home. When the user types in their email and password to login I want to pass those states to my other component i.e. So I have the users login information. However, the console.log statements show they are undefined.

Home.js in render method

```
return (
  <div>
    <HomePage signInEmail={this.state.signInEmail} signInPassword={this.state.signInPassword}/>
    <p>Account</p>
    <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
  </div>
);
```

Below is what I have tried for HomePage.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {
        noResp: ''

    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Component Mounted!');
    console.log('this.props.signInEmail  ' + this.props.signInEmail );
    console.log('this.props.signInPassword: ' + this.props.signInPassword);
}
```

The above comes to undefined. In my Home.js, I can get the values I need but I can't seem to pass these to a different component.

Comment: you have to understand what state and props are in react. Refer this https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/05/understanding-react-state-and-props/

Comment: It appears you're passing the props correctly, can you post the state of your component?

Comment: Still getting blank string. Reading the link posted below to improve my understanding but not 100% sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by

```
this.props.signInEmail 
this.props.signInPassword
```

in your HomePage.js.

When you want to pass some data from parent to child component, they are called props.

Perhaps this help! [State and Props in React](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/05/understanding-react-state-and-props/)

You can recieve props from parent component by writing

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
         super(props);
}
render(){
    return(//THE JSX you wanna return)
 }
}
```

in the child component i.e., HomePage.js in your case!

Comment: I still get a empty String/ undefined on the console

Comment: you have to recieve props too